# Why does conscio not have four principal parts?

Tags: verbs, morphology

I have been using working through some latin translations and stumbled across *conscio, -ire, -ivi* in my latin dictionary, which it lists as a transitive verb meaning "to have on one's conscience." I looked it up online a few places, and everything I've been able to find supports it as not having a fourth principal part, e.g., [here is latin-dictionary.net's definition](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/13250/conscio-conscire-conscivi)) (note the dash where the fourth principal part would normally be).

It does not appear to be a deponent verb (latin-dictionary.net, for instance, normally says "voice: deponent" for deponent verbs, e.g., [*conor*](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/conor)), correct? If so, what kind of verb is this that is not deponent but does not have a fourth principal part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, **it means that form is never attested**. The authors of the dictionary have never seen a form of *consciō* using its fourth principal part. But that's not necessarily a satisfying answer, because there are plenty of verbs that have certain forms unattested, but we can easily extrapolate what those forms would have been.

The long answer is, there are two related verbs: *consciō* "have on one's conscience" and *consciscō* "resolve upon". The bases of these are *sciō* "know" and *sciscō* "learn" (which is itself derived from *sciō*), and they look the same in the perfect system: *conscīvī*, *conscītus*.

Theoretically, then, we would expect *conscītus* to mean either "had on one's conscience" or "resolved upon" (as a participle). But we only ever see it with the latter meaning.

Is this just an accident? Possibly. Neither of those were especially common verbs; a corpus search turns up only three hits from the Classical era, two in Pliny and one in Livy. And it's entirely possible that other Latin-speakers used *conscītus* to mean "had on one's conscience" but their works didn't survive.

But, we don't have evidence for that. Since we **do** see *conscītus* used to mean "resolved upon" and **don't** see it used to mean "had on one's conscience", the authors of your dictionary seem to have decided not to list it with the latter meaning.